# Mongoose 5.3 , this.getUpdate is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When I try to execute the `update` function I got this error. It happen when I added `timestamps: true`

I navigate to the error and I got this function called in schema.js in mongoose >> lib folder.

```
function _setTimestampsOnUpdate(next) {
  applyTimestampsToUpdate(createdAt, updatedAt, this.getUpdate(),
    this.options, true);
  applyTimestampsToChildren(this);
  next();
}
```

The above function was used with `getUpdate` in `schema.js`. Please help me out with this issue.

:: SCHEMA ::

```
const assetListSchema = new Schema({userId: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User',
  required: true
  },
  name: String,
  config: {
  showAssetsLibrary: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: true
  },
  showAssetsDetails: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: true
  },
  aliasName: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 75,
    default: ""
  }
}},{ timestamps: true});
```

:: UPDATE function ::

```
assetListSchema.methods.update = async function (data) {
try {
let asst = this;
data = _.pick(data, ['showAssetsLibrary', 
'showAssetsDetails','aliasName']);
if (_.isEmpty(data)) {
  emptyError();
}
return await AssetsHierarchy.findByIdAndUpdate(asst._id, {
  config: data
}, {
  new: true,
  fields: {
    "config": 1
  }
});
} catch (err) {
 throw new Error(err.message);
}
}
```

:: ERROR ::

TypeError: this.getUpdate is not a function

at model._setTimestampsOnUpdate (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:873:56)

at callMiddlewareFunction (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:427:23)

at next (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:58:7)

at Kareem.execPre (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:86:8)

at Kareem.wrap (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:265:8)

at model.$__update (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:339:11)

at utils.promiseOrCallback.callback (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\model\applyHooks.js:80:30)

at Promise (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:246:5)

at new Promise ()

at Object.promiseOrCallback (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:245:10)

at model.objToDecorate.(anonymous function) [as update] (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\model\applyHooks.js:79:20)

at update (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\App\controllers\settings\asset-hierarchy\assetsHierarchyController.js:163:33)

at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

at next (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)

at Route.dispatch (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)

at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\inspectionApp\inspection-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Comment: It's more than likely a problem with your code and not mongoose itself

Comment: Please share your `schema` code

Comment: const assetListSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  name: String,
  config: {
    showAssetsLibrary: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: true
    },
    showAssetsDetails: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: true
    },
    aliasName: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 75,
      default: ""
    }
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

Comment: assetListSchema.methods.update = async function (data) {

  try {
    let asst = this;
    data = _.pick(data, ['showAssetsLibrary', 'showAssetsDetails', 'aliasName']);
    if (_.isEmpty(data)) {
      emptyError();
    }
    return await AssetsHierarchy.findByIdAndUpdate(asst._id, {
      config: data
    }, {
      new: true,
      fields: {
        "config": 1
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
}